# @SequenceGenerator with allocationSize>1 generates duplicate primary keys

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using above code to generate id:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seqq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqq", sequenceName = "seqq", allocationSize = 20, initialValue = 1)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

I also updated persistence.xml:

```
   <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
```

and updated ddl in database:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seqq
  INCREMENT 20
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 9171
  CACHE 1;
```

Thanks to this allocationSize = 20 is same as increment value. However, I get arbitrary errors saying duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myobjects_pkey". Often this error occurrs after first save trial.
It seems that  hibernate tries to persist entity with same Id. However START ensures that the row is higher than any existing in table id.
How to elimiate duplicate constraint error?

Answer (score 0):

try specifying the strategy as below :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqq")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    /** The identity. */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_SEQU_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "DB_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_SEQU_GENERATOR")
    public long getId() {
       return id;
    }
```

`DB_SEQ` this should be defined in `DB as sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

After setting hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true, Hibernate will produce id values starting with LASTPRODUCEDID-ALLOCATIONSIZE. I experienced the following with the default 50 allocationSize:

Before using new generator:

```
   entity.id          SEQ last number
     48847                  48847
     48848                  48848
     48849                  48849
     48850                  48850
```

After using new generator:

```
   entity.id          SEQ last number
     48801                  48851
     48802                  48852
```

So you have to increase your sequence with allocation size.
As the increase by clause of your sequence should be equal to allocationSize, this means simply querying the nextval of your sequences. You can do it with the following script:

```
 DECLARE
    v NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    FOR r IN (select sequence_name from user_sequences) LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '|| r.sequence_name ||' .NEXTVAL FROM DUAL' INTO v;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  /
```